# What is <<!END in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

Consider:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

/u01/app/oracle/middleware/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh <<!END
connect('user','pw');
p=redeploy('application');
p.printStatus();
exit();
!END
```

The above script is there to help me to perform a redeploy for weblogic application. The area I don't understand is `wlst.sh <<!END` as well as the last `!END`.

What's the function of both `!END` statements?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's a [Here Document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) -- the lines between `<<!END` and `!END` are fed to the stdin of wlst.sh

It could also be expressed as:

```bsh
echo "connect('user','pw');
p=redeploy('application');
p.printStatus();
exit();" | /u01/app/oracle/middleware/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh
```

but without the potential effects of running the command in a subshell.

It could also also be expressed as:

```bsh
echo "connect('user','pw');
p=redeploy('application');
p.printStatus();
exit();" > someFile
/u01/app/oracle/middleware/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh < someFile
rm someFile
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, it doesn't have to be "!END" - it can be any string.  Whatever string is following **<<** will mark the end of the Here Document when it's encountered a second time (I usually use just END).

Comment: Might be good to mention that while history expansion isn't typically enabled for scripts (non-interactive shells), `<<!END` would be subject to history expansion were it to be enabled. It's better to use a string that doesn't use a `!`.

Comment: Where I work, `EOHD` (for "End Of Here Document") is commonly used.

Comment: I'll use things like `END_USAGE` or `END_HTML` to give the heredoc a bit more context.

Comment: I find this discussion about the choice of the terminating string fascinating, given that I don't think I've ever seen anything except `EOF` used unless there were nested or interleaved here-documents involved.

Comment: I always use `ZZ`, and I didn't come up with that by myself.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I think the usage of EOF, which stands for "End Of File", is miss leading when used as a delimiter for a Here-Document as the file which includes the Here-Document usually doesn't end at the EOF. Also the Here-Document by itself is not a file either.